# Fail to install nvidia-driver-525 nvidia-dkms-525

Tags: ubuntu, apt, drivers, nvidia

I have a NVIDIA Jetson Xavier NX(ubuntu20.04), I want to install the nvidia-driver.BUT,It shows ERRORS every time when i try. I use "sudo apt install nvidia-driver-525 nvidia-dkms-525". How should I solve this problem?[image: error screenshot]

Comment: looks to be a conflict with `nvidia-l4t-x11` - have you tried uninstalling the conflicting package?

Comment: I try to uninstall the conflicting package, but it shows unmet dependencies and suggest an ’apt --fix-broken install, I tried that it shows a conflicting error again. It seems like an endless loop.